# How to add Text Popup upon Cards being Matched/Wrong Match

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I'm trying to add text to pop up in a Picture Matching Quiz - if the wrong cards are matched "Please try again" which timeouts and if the correct cards are matched a Textbox with a Text corresponding to what set was matched which can be clicked away to then try the next set.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasSelectCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;

function selectCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('select');

  if (!hasSelectCard) {
    hasSelectCard = true;
    firstCard = this;
    return;
  }

  secondCard = this;
  lockBoard = true;

  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;
  isMatch ? disableCards() : unselectCards();
  isMatch ? disableCards() : unselectCards();

}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', selectCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', selectCard);

  resetBoard();
}


function unselectCards() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('select');
    secondCard.classList.remove('select');

    resetBoard();
  }, 1500);
}

function resetBoard() {
  [hasSelectCard, lockBoard] = [false, false];
  [firstCard, secondCard] = [null, null];
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let ramdomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14);
    card.style.order = ramdomPos;
  });
})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', selectCard));
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* styles.css */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  background: #060AB2;
}

.memory-game {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.memory-card.select {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1C7CCC;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.text {
  font: 16px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #22d;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.textwrong {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.textwrong {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.textright {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Schmetterlingsquiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="memory-game">
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Atlasspinner">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Atlasspinner.jpg" alt="Atlasspinner">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Atlasspinner.jpg" alt="Atlasspinner">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Atlasspinner">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Atlasspinner-Raupe.jpg" alt="Atlasspinner-Raupe">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Atlasspinner-Raupe.jpg" alt="Atlasspinner-Raupe">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Bananenfalter">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Bananenfalter.jpg" alt="Bananenfalter">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Bananenfalter.jpg" alt="Bananenfalter">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Bananenfalter">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Bananenfalter-Raupe.jpg" alt="Bananenfalter-Raupe">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Bananenfalter-Raupe.jpg" alt="Bananenfalter-Raupe">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Distelfalter">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Distelfalter.jpg" alt="Distelfalter">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Distelfalter.jpg" alt="Distelfalter">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Distelfalter">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Distelfalter-Raupe.jpg" alt="Distelfalter-Raupe">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Distelfalter-Raupe.jpg" alt="Distelfalter-Raupe">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Grosser-Schillerfalter">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Grosser-Schillerfalter.jpg" alt="Grosser-Schillerfalter">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Grosser-Schillerfalter.jpg" alt="Grosser-Schillerfalter">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Grosser-Schillerfalter">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Grosser-Schillerfalter-Raupe.jpg" alt="Grosser-Schillerfalter-Raupe">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Grosser-Schillerfalter-Raupe.jpg" alt="Grosser-Schillerfalter-Raupe">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Rotes-Ordensband">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Rotes-Ordensband.jpg" alt="Rotes-Ordensband">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Rotes-Ordensband.jpg" alt="Rotes-Ordensband">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Rotes-Ordensband">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Rotes-Ordensband-Raupe.jpg" alt="Rotes-Ordensband-Raupe">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Rotes-Ordensband-Raupe.jpg" alt="Rotes-Ordensband-Raupe">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Taubenschwaenzchen">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Taubenschwaenzchen.jpg" alt="Taubenschwaenzchen">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Taubenschwaenzchen.jpg" alt="Taubenschwaenzchen">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Taubenschwaenzchen">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Taubenschwaenzchen-Raupe.jpg" alt="Taubenschwaenzchen-Raupe">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Taubenschwaenzchen-Raupe.jpg" alt="Taubenschwaenzchen-Raupe">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Zitronenfalter">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Zitronenfalter.jpg" alt="Zitronenfalter">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Zitronenfalter.jpg" alt="Zitronenfalter">
      </div>
      <div class="memory-card" data-framework="Zitronenfalter">
        <img class="front-face" src="img/Zitronenfalter-Raupe.jpg" alt="Zitronenfalter-Raupe">
        <img class="back-face" src="img/Zitronenfalter-Raupe.jpg" alt="Zitronenfalter-Raupe">
      </div>
      <div style="display:none" class="textwrong">
        Please try again. 
      </div>
      <div style="display:none" class="textcorecct" data-framework="Atlasspinner">
        Placeholder
      </div>
      <div style="display:none" class="textcorecct" data-framework="Bananenfalter">
        Placeholder
      </div>
      <div style="display:none" class="textcorecct" data-framework="Distelfalter">
        Placeholder
      </div>
      <div style="display:none" class="textcorecct" data-framework="Grosser-Schillerfalter">
        Placeholder
      </div>
      <div style="display:none" class="textcorecct" data-framework="Rotes-Ordensband">
        Placeholder
      </div>
      <div style="display:none" class="textcorecct" data-framework="Taubenschwaenzchen">
        Placeholder
      </div>
      <div style="display:none" class="textcorecct" data-framework="Zitronenfalter">
        Placeholder
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="./scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried several tutorials online to fit them into this code, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).